# Keep file data always available to Bash, without repeated execution (also after reboot)

Tags: bash, command-line, variable, alias, reboot

I have a file named `~/myScripts/assignments.sh` which contains various assignments such as variables and aliases. Here's a taste from that file:

```
drt="/var/www/html"
rss="/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service"

alias drt="cd ${drt}"
alias rss="${rss}"
```

I use these assignments frequently from the moment I finished installing my operating system, especially to write neater scripts for installation, configuration and maintenance of my webserver and adjacent software.

Thus, it's vital that this file will **always be exported**, that its data will always be available in all Bash sessions, immediately after any Bash session has started (also after a `reboot`).

To achieve that, I thought of the following lousy script:

```
source ~/myScripts/assignments.sh # Immediate availability;
printf "\n%s" "source ~/myScripts/assignments.sh" >> ~/.profile
cat > "cron_daily.sh" <<< "source ~/myScripts/assignments.sh"

crontab <<-"CRONTAB"
    0 0 * * * ~/myScripts/cron_daily.sh # Permanent availability (after the one minute gap);
CRONTAB
```

What will be a good approach to achieve the state I described above?

### Update

The reason I'd think to avoid sourcing the file, then add `source ~/myScripts/assignments.sh` inside bash.bashrc is that I've seen some devops reluctant from sourcing `bash.bashrc` in general. Although, when the file isn't customized, or has just such small change it is generally not a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the assignments are necessary for "all" bash-sessions, simply put the file in somewhere like `/etc/assignments` and source it globally from `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Append this into `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
source /etc/assignments
```

That way, you have all your definitions available in all bash-sessions, for every user, and can maintain the information in a separate file.